# How to sort a table at launch

Tags: bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap table @ https://bootstrap-table.com/

The table looks great, is searchable, sortable, and has pagination but I don't know how to tell it to say sort by the second column in ascending order or sort by the third column in descending order as soon as the table is rendered.  How can I do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164654/bootstrap-table-is-it-possible-to-call-the-function-which-sorts-rows-by-column

Comment: That was exactly what I needed thanks!

Answer (score 0):

kmoser suggested [Bootstrap table: is it possible to call the function which sorts rows by column from code (without clicking the header)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164654/bootstrap-table-is-it-possible-to-call-the-function-which-sorts-rows-by-column) which was exactly what I needed...

1. add `data-sort-name='field_name_here'` to table element
2. add `data-sort-order='desc'` or `'asc'` to table element
3. your TH's should have `data-field='field_name_here'` in them

Thanks kmoser for your help!